# Sublime text 3 - Colouring specific characters C#

Tags: c#, sublimetext3

(Pre-Warning UK spelling)

Hi all,
I'm trying to change my syntax colours on Sublime Text 3 I've had a google and haven't found much that i can make sense of. What I'm looking for is to make specific characters a different foreground colour. So for example

```
string[] name = {"Jack","James","...","John"};
```

My hope is that I could change the `"` character specifically to a different colour. So rather than the `"Jack"` all being in green I would have the `"` in a Dark Red and the `Jack` in Yellow. I have already got the whole thing in yellow I would just like to if at all possible change the `"` into red.

I'm using `.sublime-colour-scheme` extension if that is any help.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scopes you're looking for are `punctuation.definition.string.begin.cs` and `punctuation.definition.string.end.cs`. If you want to color *all* quotes in any language, just drop the `.cs` at the end of each. So, the rule in your `.sublime-color-scheme` file would be like so:

```json
{
    "name": "String quotes",
    "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.begin, punctuation.definition.string.end",
    "foreground": "#8A0F11" // Feel free to change this to another deep red
},
```